# Show values from query in a table using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, php-5.3

I have a problem with my code, So I have an array and I pass to template, the array is like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ref_article] => 1903
        [ref_fournisseur] => sdsds
        [lien_fournisseur] => www.four.com
        [prix_ht] => 14.00
        [gifts_number] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ref_article] => 1907
        [ref_fournisseur] => sdsds
        [lien_fournisseur] => www.four.com
        [prix_ht] => 12.00
        [gifts_number] => 1
    )

)
```

Now in template I do :

```
for (var item in result) {
    document.getElementById('order_information').setAttribute('class','display-on');
    document.getElementById('order_information').setAttribute('class','table');

    var html = '<td>' + result[item]['ref_article'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[item]['ref_fournisseur'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + 'description' + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + result[item]['lien_fournisseur'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[item]['prix_ht'] + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + 'disponibilite' + 
                '<td>' + result[item]['gifts_number'] + '</td>';
    $("#content-order").html(html);
    console.log(result[item]['ref_article']);
}
```

The problem is that only the last `<td></td>` shows on the page, in this case only the article with `[ref_article] = 1907`. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The issue is because you are using `html()` to add the content - this will overwrite any pre-existing content in the `#content-order` element. Instead, try using `append()`:

```
$("#content-order").append(html);
```

Also note that you can amend your first two lines to use a jQuery selector and the `addClass()` method:

```
$('#order_information').addClass('display-on table');
```

If you want to clear information added from a previous request you can use `.empty()` before the `for` loop that appends new content. Here's a full example:

```
// $.ajax({...

success: function(result) {
    $("#content-order").empty(); // remove existing content
    $('#order_information').addClass('display-on table');

    for (var item in result) {
        var html = '<td>' + result[item]['ref_article'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[item]['ref_fournisseur'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>description</td>' + // removed redundant string concatenation
                '<td>' + result[item]['lien_fournisseur'] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + result[item]['prix_ht'] + '</td>'+
                '<td>disponibilite</td>' + // added missing </td>
                '<td>' + result[item]['gifts_number'] + '</td>';
        $("#content-order").append(html);
        console.log(result[item]['ref_article']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
var html = '<table>';
for (var item in result) {
    html += '<td>' + result[item]['ref_article'] + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + result[item]['ref_fournisseur'] + '</td>' +
        '<td>description</td>' + // removed redundant string concatenation
    '<td>' + result[item]['lien_fournisseur'] + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + result[item]['prix_ht'] + '</td>' +
        '<td>disponibilite</td>' + // added missing </td>
    '<td>' + result[item]['gifts_number'] + '</td>';

    console.log(result[item]['ref_article']);
}
html += '</table>';
$("#content-order").html(html);
```